# edit an attribute in core data

Tags: xcode, core-data, ios5

here is my code to edit a particular attribute and save it to the sqlite DB but i can't save the changes to the DB.

```
-(void)changeMemberKey
{
  NSEntityDescription *entityDesc=[NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"Table1" inManagedObjectContext:context];
  NSFetchRequest *request=[[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
  NSPredicate *predicate=[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"(member_id=Null)"];
  [request setPredicate:predicate];
  [request setEntity:entityDesc];
  Table1 *matches;
  NSError *error;

  NSArray *objects=[context executeFetchRequest:request error:&error];
  NSLog(@"Object count===%d",[objects count]);
  for(int i=0;i<[objects count];i++)
  {
    matches=[objects objectAtIndex:i];
    Table1 *data=(Table1 *)matches;
    NSLog(@"Data before===%@",data);
    [data setValue:memberKey forKey:@"member_id"];
    [context save:&error];
    NSLog(@"Data after====%@",data);
    data=nil;
  }

  entityDesc=nil;
  request=nil;
  matches=nil;
  error=nil;
  objects=nil;
}
```

Comment: Try to replace `[context save:&error];` to `if (! [context save:&error]) NSLog(@"Couldn't save data! Error:%@", [error description]);`. Then you can see whether you saved succeed. If not, edit your question to add the log.

Comment: Actually, you can just save your data after `for` loop, just once, ya. :)

Comment: thanks for your suggestion. i edited my code like (! [context save:&error]) NSLog(@"Couldn't save data! Error:%@", [error description]); but there is no error,the context is saved but it is not reflected in the Data base

Comment: Did there any log output (like _'Data before'_ or something else)? And btw, how do you declare your `context`?

Comment: yes get the log output correctly,that means Data before gives output with null memberid and Data after gives the output with new memberid. the declaration of context is like as follows:  NSManagedObjectContext *context; in .h and 
        appDelegate=(AppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate]; in .m files

        context=[appDelegate managedObjectContext];

Answer (score 0):

Try to replace the `for` loop to

```
for(Table1 * data in objects)
  data.member_id = memberKey;

if (! [context save:&error])
  NSLog(@"Couldn't save data! Error:%@", [error description]);
```

Not sure whether it'll work or not, just take a try. Anyway, it's cleaner.